# No fingerprint login option with Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: login, acer, 20.10, fingerprint-reader

I have an Acer swift 3 with built-in fingerprint reader and am running Ubuntu 20.10.  I followed the Ubuntu guide to enable fingerprint login and when I get to Users in settings there is no option to enable fingerprint login.  Any helps or tips would be great.  Thanks.